# Perl regex vs. Python regex non-capture seems to work differently

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to capture the numbers in a decimal inches statement without catching the `"`.  An expression that works well in Perl seems to fail in Python and I can't see why.

In the following two expressions I expect to see `1` and `1.5` but in Python see instead `1"` and `1.5"` and I expect them to work the same.  What am I missing?

#### Perl:

```
  DB<15> x '1"' =~ m{^(?:(\d+(?:\.\d+)*)")}  
0  1
  DB<16> x '1.5"' =~ m{^(?:(\d+(?:\.\d+)*)")}
0  1.5
```

#### Python:

```
>>> re.search(r'^(?:(\d+(?:\.\d+)*)")', '1"').group()
'1"'
>>> re.search(r'^(?:(\d+(?:\.\d+)*)")', '1.5"').group()
'1.5"'
```

Ultimately I was hoping to use an expression like:^(?:(\d+)\')|(?:(\d+(?:.\d+)*)") to match either 1' or 1" or 1.5" and by the location of the match, tell which expression worked.  hwnd pointed out the 'findall' which I had previously overlooked so I expect my solution will look something like:

```
>>> re.findall(r'^(?:(\d+)\')|(?:(\d+(?:\.\d+)*)")', '1\'')
[('1', '')]
>>> re.findall(r'(?:(\d+)\')|(?:(\d+(?:\.\d+)*)")', '1\' 1" 1.5"')
[('1', ''), ('', '1'), ('', '1.5')]
```

Here is another interesting possibility using finditer/groupdict/comprehension:

```
>>> [m.groupdict() for m in re.finditer(r'(?P<feet>(\d+)\')|(?P<inches>(\d+(?:\.\d+)*)")', '1\' 1" 1.5"')]
[{'feet': "1'", 'inches': None},
 {'feet': None, 'inches': '1"'},
 {'feet': None, 'inches': '1.5"'}]
```

Thank you all for another enlightening trip into Python.

Comment: Are you sure you're not getting the complete matching text rather than the text matched by the first capture in Python?

Comment: What's the expected output for `1.2.4"`?

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary Presumably, the pattern should be `^(?:(\d+(?:\.\d+){0,1})")`

Comment: Try: `'^(?<![!\d.])(?:((\d+)?((?:\.\d+)?(?="))))'` works without `group(1)`.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary The OP wants this to be part of a larger pattern which is used to extract information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily do..

```
import re

string = 'I have values "1" and "1.5" also "12.555"'
m = re.findall(r'\"(\d+|\d+\.\d+)\"', string)
print ", " . join(m)
```

Output:

```
1, 1.5, 12.555
```

Answer (score 5):

Try:

```
re.search(r'^(?:(\d+(?:\.\d+)*)")', '1.5"').group(1)
```

See [re](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#match-objects):

> `group([group1, ...])`
>
> Returns one or more subgroups of the match. If there is a single argument, the result is a single string; if there are multiple arguments, the result is a tuple with one item per argument. Without arguments, group1 defaults to zero **(the whole match is returned)**. If a `groupN` argument is zero, the corresponding return value is the entire matching string; if it is in the inclusive range [1..99], it is the string matching the corresponding parenthesized group. (*emphasis mine*)

Now, you can use named capture groups both in Perl (unless you are stuck with a very old version) and Python.

So, I would actually recommend:

```
>>> re.search(r'^(?:(?P<inches>\d+(?:\.\d+){0,1})")', '1.5"').groupdict()['inches']
'1.5'
```

Comment: It surprises me that group is catching a non-capture expression.  I was hoping to use this as one part of a larger regex and don't know how many matches I will receive.  Thank you Sinan.

Comment: This is the correct answer, the others are wrong. Perl returns in list context an array of matched subgroups $1...$*n*, thus to match that in python you want to get group(1).

Comment: AUGH!  Bit again.  Thank you.

Comment: Ah -- interesting.  I think that will work and also a bit more self-documenting than the findall solution.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You're putting the trailing `"` in the group.  Instead, try:

```
re.search(r'^(?:(\d+(?:\.\d+)*))(?=")', '1.5"').group()
```